# Unable to insert DateTime.now hours minutes and seconds to Database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a column of `Datetime` type in a SQL Server table.

When I do:

```
Response.Write(DateTime.Now);
```

I get the current date and the exact time.

But, when I insert it into my database it shows as the date and the time stamp is always:

```
12:00:00 AM
```

I need the time to be inserted as well as the date, not only the date and then 12:00:00 AM.

Insert code:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO tblProject (ProjectStatus,ProjectLastUpdated) VALUES ('" + txtAddress.Text + "', '" + DateTime.Now + "')";
```

Comment: Can you show the code that inserts the value in the db?

Comment: what's the column type in the database?

Comment: I would strongly recommend that you use prepared statements with parameters and not dynamic sql. This is a sql injection accident waiting to happen. Look into Ado.Net sql parameters or an ORM

Comment: @TGH hmm... Wow, I really haven't thought about that... This will require a lot of changes.. I'm not that experienced with web development... I was just building a database to help my dad with managing some data at work... Thanks a lot for the heads up!

Comment: @TGH But there is no where a place on my website where a customer or any person can input a query

Comment: Is "txtAddress.Text" not user-inputted? In case you aren't familiar, the "sql injection" that @TGH mentioned could happen here if someone typed in something along the lines of, say, "', GETDATE()); DROP TABLE tblProject;" Clearly, that would be far from ideal. And it really shouldn't take "a lot of changes" to implement.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Fortunately for me, The only input a user can enter is an ID and password which is limited to 9 chars, Is there a any kind of sql command that can affect my data that's only 9 chars long?

Comment: @user3238509, I'm inclined to say no. That's definitely not much room. But that said, it's kind of a matter of principle. I know that's not the greatest reason in the world to go through extra work, but I'd just warn against taking those sorts of unnecessary risks because things tend to not go as planned. Especially since you can just write a helper function to handle the parameters and have it right in a few moments. Take a look at the example on [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Thank you very much, on this website, I'll leave it at is, any other project I'll definitely be adopting that method! Thanks again.

Comment: Be sure to read about [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).  Also consider [The Case Against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just about guarantee you that your problem stems from using the wrong column type. There are a handful of date-related types in SQL, and my guess is that you're using `DATE` as compared to `DATETIME`. Try swapping the column types with a simple `ALTER TABLE tblProject ALTER COLUMN ProjectLastUpdated DATETIME` and I bet your problems will be resolved.

Also, as a couple people mentioned, you should definitely switch to using SQL parameters. The way you're doing it now uses the system's current formatting to build the DateTime string, which will *almost* always work. If you switch to using SQL parameters, it will always work. At least, as much as any programming can depend on an "always."

Comment: Ugh! I knew that the i had some rookie mistake here somewhere! Thanks a lot and thank you for putting time to answer my question!